# Sending the data to server as URL encoded in jQuery Ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently supporting a project.In Some places of the code, the ajax calls will be like below

```js
var myObj = [
  { name: "first", value: "Rick" },
  { name: "last", value: "Astley" },
  { name: "job", value: "Rock Star" }
];

$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"https://example.com",
   contentType:"application/json",
   data:myObj,
   success:function(data){
       console.log(data)
   }
});
```

But in some other places the ajax call will be like below

```js
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://example.com"+"?"+$.param(myObj);
    contentType:"application/json",
    data:{},
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

In the above code ,instead of sending the data to the server with data property,
the data is send along with the url using $.param(myObj).What is the difference between these methods.is there any specific reason to use either of these methods

Comment: there are not much difference but the catch is , the data parameter is prefered thats why they provided that for you, also your code becomes clean and more readable,I guess Jquery will proccess it for you when you use the data param

Comment: You can't send json data using "GET" method, You have to pass data in url or change "GET" method to "POST"

Comment: There is no difference. jQuery uses `$.param()` to format the `data` property into the query string for GET requests so it's functionally identical. FYI, you should not have a `;` after `+$.param(myObj)`, it should be a `,`

Answer (score 1):

GET requests take the data and encode it into the URL, so they are essentially the same. It is worth noting that while the data in GET requests can be passed both ways, POST requests pass the data through the message body of an HTML request, not the URL. Therefore, I think the first is much better practice, as it is applicable to both request types.

Answer (score 0):

The first is passing the data by writing the params in the data key of the ajax function, 
the second is passing the data by writing the params in the url itself.
Both of them are GET requests, the the way of passing data is a bit diff.
In both the cases, the data will ultimately be passed as 
 `?&first=Rick&last=Astley&job=Rock+Star`